# Profiling a Notebook - IPython

Tags: profiling, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Does IPython Notebook come with a method to profile its cells contents?

If not, how can I profile a part of a cell or the entire notebook?

Comment: My favourite profiling technique is %timeit but there are a lot more possibilities as shown e.g. [here](http://pynash.org/2013/03/06/timing-and-profiling.html)

Answer (score 6):

IPython Notebook has the very handy `%prun` and `%%prun` commands. `%prun` is used to profile one line of code, and `%%prun` is used to profile an entire cell.

You can find the documentation here: http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-prun

This is a short usage example:

```
%%prun -s cumulative

import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as la

for i in range(30):
    a = np.random.randint(100,size=(1000, 1000))
    la.inv(a)
```

If you execute this cell, the output is something like

```
1053 function calls in 4.152 seconds

Ordered by: cumulative time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.001    0.001    4.152    4.152 <string>:3(<module>)
   30    3.502    0.117    3.505    0.117 basic.py:612(inv)
   30    0.646    0.022    0.646    0.022 {method 'randint' of 'mtrand.RandomState' objects}
   30    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.000 lapack.py:382(get_lapack_funcs)
```